# Deserializing a Json message from an IoT Device in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json-deserialization

I am new to C# and I am trying to deserialize a message coming from a Raspberry Pi running Azure IoT Edge (I'm using Visual Studio 2019 with  Newtonsoft.Json and Newtonsoft.Json.Linq). However, I am unable to retrieve values from the message.

I have tried to convert it to an array and an object and then call the values.

The message is the following:

```
messageBody = "[{\"Tag\": \"Apple\", \"Probability\": 0.0012170099653303623}]"
```

And I used the following lines to deserialize it:

```
JArray jsonArray = JArray.Parse(messageBody);
var jsonObjects = jsonArray.OfType<JObject>().ToList();
```

And I would like to assign the attributes Tag and Probability to fruit and probability respectively.

```
string fruit = jsonObjects.Tag;
var probability = jsonObjects.Probability;
```

However, I get the error 'List does not contain a definition for Probabilty' and 'List does not contain a definition for Tag'

Comment: Create a new class with a string and a decimal property, use the same names (Tag and Probability).  Then use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NameOfYourNewClass>(messageBody)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add new C# Class

```
public class JsonModel{
public string Tag {get;set;}
public double Probability {get;set;}
}

var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonModel>>(message);
```

Comment: I don't believe a list is needed if its only one record.

Comment: The json body is in array format [{}] not object {}

Comment: Thank you this works since my message is a Json array. This outputs a list which then allows to call each item of such list. Thank you :)